# OpenCV C++ find contour and get pixel value

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to find contour and get a cropped image from the original image.

Then, I tried to get pixel values from the cropped image.

So far, I was able to extract the specific image from the original image like I posted below.

And here is a code for how I extract it.

```
cv::Mat frame, copyimg;
cv::Mat star = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\star\\starcircle.png");

cv::cvtColor(star, frame, CV_BGR2HSV);
cv::inRange(frame, cv::Scalar(20, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(30, 255, 255), frame);

copyimg = (frame.size(), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0));

cv::add(star, cv::Scalar(0), copyimg, frame);

cv::imshow("Converted image", frame);
cv::imshow("Original image", star);
cv::imshow("Copy", copyimg);
```

And I was able to crop the yellow part like

[image]

However, when I got this image and tried to get pixel values from the yellow parts with the code below, it read out all of the pixels of the converted image.

In other words, it gives RGB values from the entire pixel, not for the cropped yellow part of the image.

Here is the code for get pixel values from the image.

```
int hei = copyimg.rows;
int wid = copyimg.cols;

int corow = hei * wid;

double b, g, r = 0.0;

for (int x = 0; x < hei; x++) {      
    for (int y = 0; y < wid; y++) {             
        b += copyimg.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[0];
        g += copyimg.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[1];
        r += copyimg.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[2];
    }
}

cout << "$$ Red(R), Green(G), Blue(B) $$" << " \n\n";
cout << "avg_R: " << r / corow << " \n"; // red value
cout << "avg_G: " << g / corow << " \n"; // green value
cout << "avg_B: " << b / corow << " \n\n"; // blue value
```

So, I wish to combine these two codes and get pixel values from the contoured image (only yellow part).

Please help me out this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: after `inRange`, you have a mask. Use it to check inside your for loops if the pixel you are considering is inside the mask or not. You should also have a look at [cv::mean](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga191389f8a0e58180bb13a727782cd461) function

Comment: Hi, Miki Thank you for your answer. It is really helpful!! And I tried to code the if statement inside for loop. So, I used the if statement like if (frame != Scalar(0,0,0)), but I have an error for there is no operator, ' !='. I tried to extract pixel values from the only yellow parts. So, what is the correct 'if statement' to extract only yellow parts?

Comment: Like this

for (int x = 0; x < hei; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < wid; y++) {
   
   if (frame != cv::Scalar(0,0,0)) {
    b += copyimg.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[0];
    g += copyimg.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[1];
    r += copyimg.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[2];
   }
  }
 }

Comment: I tried to rule out all of the black pixels from the copyimg.

Comment: if (frame.at<unsigned char>(x, y) > 0) {
    b += star.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[0];
    g += star.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[1];
    r += star.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[2];
   }

Comment: This is what I changed from the original code. However, I think that I got a mask pixel value (black part), not for the inside mask value (yellow part) from the code above.

Comment: And further, I changed the code a little bit, but it gives me red circle values;;

if (frame.at<unsigned char>(x, y) > 0 ) {
    
   }
   else {
    b += star.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[0];
    g += star.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[1];
    r += star.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[2];
   }